# Xamarin Installation: Error, the system cannot find the file specified

Tags: xamarin

When I run my vstoolsforxamarin.exe, the Xamarin Installer, it just gives me an error;

> Error
>
> The System cannot find the file specified.

The picture is located [here](https://gyazo.com/bdd0b9a9b281182acab5a274b294e0b1).
I have Visual Studio Community 2015 installed. Is this a common error? Has anyone experienced it before? Thank you :)